# CarPlay keeps crashing Pioneer stereo receiver

Tags: iphone, ios, car-integration, sound-volume

This issue only started for me yesterday, as everything was working fine the day before. Every time I plug my 12 Pro Max into the Pioneer stereo, it completely restarts the head unit over and over. My friend plugged his iPhone into it, with no issues. Not sure how this is happening. I’m using a genuine Apple cable, I’m running the latest version of iOS, I’ve tried restarting, and nothing works. Extremely frustrating situation so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this after updating the iOS?

Comment: Nope, I had been on the latest version since it came out and CarPlay had worked fine until the other day. Not sure what caused it to start glitching out like this all of the sudden.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the phone.
Works for me. Mine does it every so often too. I've had one occasion in the past when I had to reset the phone & restore from iTunes before it stopped doing it.

As a precaution, check the cable & plugs/sockets are clean [assuming you're not using Bluetooth]; intermittent connection can do odd things too.

Mine's an SPH-DA120 [now a few years old] YMMV on newer models.